I was doing an activity to my college on MYSQL workbench and I noticed the following errors:
CREATE PROCEDURE InserirLocacao(
    p_DataHoraPedido DATETIME,
    p_CodigoCliente INT,
    p_DataInicioLocacao DATE,
    p_CodigoAgenciaModeloDisponivelRetirada INT,
    p_QtdDiasAluguel INT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE idadeCliente int;

    -- Calcula a idade do cliente com base na data de nascimento
    SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, DataNascimento, CURDATE()) INTO idadeCliente FROM Cliente WHERE CodigoCliente = p_CodigoCliente

    -- Verifica se o cliente tem 18 anos ou mais
    IF idadeCliente < 18 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cliente menor de idade não pode realizar locação.';
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    -- Verifica se a quantidade de dias de aluguel é igual ou superior a 10
    IF p_QtdDiasAluguel < 10 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Quantidade de dias de aluguel deve ser igual ou superior a 10.';
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    -- Insere a locação na tabela Locacao
    INSERT INTO Locacao 
    (DataHoraPedido, CodigoCliente, DataInicioLocacao, CodigoAgenciaModeloDisponivelRetirada, QtdDias)
    values
    (teste, teste, teste, teste, teste, teste)

on "DECLARE idadeCliente int;" it's saying: statement incomplete
and every IF, RETURN, END I have a "not valid position" or "is not valid in this position"
I believe just the DECLARE line is incorrect, but I'm not finding the error, can somebody help?
I searched everywhere

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question both are relevant here. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

The function DATEDIFF expects two arguments, see the documentation, you try to execute it with three.

You mix MySQL and SQL Server syntax. In MySQL: 1) DATEDIFF accepts 2 arguments only; 2) Each separate statement must be terminated with delimiter; 3) RETURN statement cannot be used in the stored procedure; 4) RETURN must be accompanied with the scalar-type expression; 5) BEGIN must accompanied with END;

The MySQL equivalent to your attempted datediff is timestampdiff.  Use leave, not return, in procedures; return is for functions

As a beginner, you are better off not trying to throw a big block of code at it and work through the errors.  Instead start with an empty stored procedure, then add one or two lines at a time to it, each time verifying it succeeds and does what you expect.

As others have already commented above plus, you need to change the delimiter so that ; within the definition of your stored procedure does not indicate the end of the SP create. You are missing ; after first SELECT statement.
